# Given X, determine n, where X is n-th ugly number

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, optimization, numbers

> "Ugly numbers are numbers whose only prime factors are 2, 3 or 5. The
>   sequence 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, … shows the first 11 ugly
>   numbers. By convention, 1 is included."

Given number X, determine the order of X in that sequence.
Example : X = 12, output : 10.

I made a brute force algorithm, which runs in O(XlogX):

```
long long cnt = 0;
for(long long i = 1; i<X; i++)
{
  long long tmp = i;
  while(tmp % 2 == 0) tmp/=2;
  while(tmp % 3 == 0) tmp/=3;
  while(tmp % 5 == 0) tmp/=5;
  if(tmp == 1) cnt ++;
}
cout << cnt+1 << endl;
```

However, X might be 1e18 and there might be 10^5 queries, each query gives us a number X.

Does anyone know a more efficient algorithm to perform this operation? Thank you.

Comment: Questions like this generally need you to know, research, or discover a sneaky math trick that vastly reduces the amount of computing you need to perform.

Comment: thank you. I've generated first 11000 ugly numbers in O(11000) and it worked. the 11000th ugly number > 1e18.

Answer (score 0):

**Single Query**

You can obtain the position `n` of `X` by counting the number of ugly numbers below `X` using the following algorithm:

```
int get_position(long long X)
{
    int n = 0;
    for(long long n2=1; n2<=X; n2*=2)
        for(long long n3=n2; n3<=X; n3*=3)
            for(long long n5=n3; n5<=X; n5*=5)
                ++n;
    return n;
}
```

The algorithm loops over all combination of 2, 3, and 5 multiples, and runs in `O(n)`, where `n~log(X)³`.

**Multiple Queries**

If you want to repeat the operation multiple times, you can keep a table to perform binary searches:

```
struct ugly_numbers
{
    std::vector<long long> numbers{1};

    int get_position(long long X)
    {
        if(X>numbers.back())
        {
            std::set<long long> number_set;
            for(long long n2=1; n2<=X; n2*=2)
                for(long long n3=n2; n3<=X; n3*=3)
                    for(long long n5=n3; n5<=X; n5*=5)
                        number_set.insert(n5);
            numbers.assign(number_set.begin(), number_set.end());
        }
        auto value_it = std::upper_bound(numbers.begin(),numbers.end(),X);
        return (int)std::distance(numbers.begin(),value_it);
    }
};
```

This algorithm runs in `O(log(n))` when the number is part of the cache, and in `O(n*log(n))` when the cache needs to be recreated. Alternatively, you can create the cache beforehand using the greatest expected number to amortize the cost of cache creation.

**Avoiding Overflow**

For queries of numbers close to the maximum value of type `long long`, overflow errors and infinite loops may occur. To avoid that, use the following code (and use a similar logic with the amortized version):

```
int get_position(long long X)
{
    int n=0;
    long long max_n2 = std::min(X,std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 2);
    long long max_n3 = std::min(X,std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 3);
    long long max_n5 = std::min(X,std::numeric_limits<long long>::max() / 5);
    for(long long n2=1; n2<=max_n2; n2*=2)
        for(long long n3=n2; n3<=max_n3; n3*=3)
            for(long long n5=n3; n5<=max_n5; n5*=5)
                ++n;
    return n;
}
```